# ionic build cordova android gives error " UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 "

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build.gradle, phonegap

I am trying to build and ionic project as an apk. When I do `ionic cordova build android` it gives the following error

```
Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova
[23:35:31]  build dev started ...
[23:35:31]  clean started ...
[23:35:31]  clean finished in 20 ms
[23:35:31]  copy started ...
[23:35:31]  deeplinks started ...
[23:35:31]  deeplinks finished in 75 ms
[23:35:31]  transpile started ...
[23:35:35]  transpile finished in 3.87 s
[23:35:35]  preprocess started ...
[23:35:35]  preprocess finished in 33 ms
[23:35:35]  webpack started ...
[23:35:35]  copy finished in 4.25 s
[23:35:40]  webpack finished in 4.78 s
[23:35:40]  sass started ...
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
[23:35:41]  sass finished in 1.02 s
[23:35:41]  postprocess started ...
[23:35:41]  postprocess finished in 77 ms
[23:35:41]  lint started ...
[23:35:41]  build dev finished in 10.20 s
> cordova build android --debug

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
Android Studio project detected

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\makarov\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
[23:35:44]  lint finished in 3.65 s
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\My_Files\Projects\MyNoteApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.gradle' line: 84

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
> build_ihrdqe7fln9qjqpg3xt8ghgr$_run_closure3$_closure11$_closure12$_closure13$_closure14

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
(node:11172) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\My_Files\Projects\MyNoteApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.gradle' line: 84

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
> build_ihrdqe7fln9qjqpg3xt8ghgr$_run_closure3$_closure11$_closure12$_closure13$_closure14

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\My_Files\Projects\MyNoteApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
(node:11172) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11172) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

When I do `cordova platform ls` I get this output

```
Installed platforms:
  android 7.0.0
Available platforms:
  browser ~5.0.1
  ios ~4.5.4
  osx ~4.0.1
  windows ~5.0.0
  www ^3.12.0
```

My Ionic version is 3 and I have Android SDK Platform-Tools 27 installed.

I also tried to build this app using PhoneGap too. When testing by hosting the app using PhoneGap desktop and using PhoneGap app on my phone, the app works fine including any native API that I am using (i.e. Toasts). When I go to PhoneGap build website and build my app into APK and run it on my phone I only get a white screen and nothing comes up.

Comment: try `cordova build android --verbose` and see if you get more logs

Comment: Also are you using any cordova plugins?

Comment: if I add verbose to the command it only gives a couple of extra lines of logs in the beginning, nothing related to the error. I am using the following plugins - cordova-plugin-x-toast,cordova-plugin-whitelist,cordova-plugin-device,cordova-plugin-splashscreen,cordova-plugin-ionic-webview,cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard

Comment: Just to be clear.. did you run `ionic cordova build android --verbose` or just `cordova build android --verbose`? Because there is an issue with verbose option https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2919

Comment: I did `ionic cordova build android --verbose`. Now I did `cordova build android --verbose` and this is the output [imgur](https://imgur.com/hLcNUD3)

Comment: Sorry..I am not able to really tell from the error logs. Will answer if I figure it out